# Best way to model this data, qfit or fpfit? How to get equation?

Tags: regression, fitting, curve-fitting

So I have this relationship, which is obviously not linear. The purpose is to see if there is (and what kind of) a relationship between FRAG (test score) and MD-R (mm^2/s). There are other covariates like age and gender that I would like to account for, ideally, but I don't know how if I can't do normal linear multiple regression.
The distribution was not normal after testing with Shapiro-Wilk. What is the best way to describe the relationship? Here, I have fitted a qfit line, which doesn't look too bad, but it seems to be like the slope should be bigger, and the upper observations don't seem like outliers. Do you think qfit is a good choice here? fpfit doesn't come up too different. Also, how do I get the equation of this line?

Finally, how to I do a qfit with covariates and get the equation? (there may be an interaction that causes these outliers to be higher I guess and I would like to see that).

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: (1) You mention an "interaction": does this mean you have other independent variables? (2) What is `MD_R` and what are its units of measurement? (3) What is the purpose of this curve-fitting exercise? (Without this last bit of information, we have no basis to opine on whether any choice is "good" or not.)

Comment: The purpose is to see if there is (and what kind of) a relationship between FRAG (test score) and MD-R (mm^2/s). There are other covariates like age and gender that I would like to account for, ideally, but I don't know how if I can't do normal linear multiple regression.

Comment: I don't (yet) see any indication that you cannot do multiple regression.  The apparent curvature and heteroscedasticity could both be cleared up once you introduce additional variables.  Why don't you do that first, study the residuals after you have included all relevant variables, and only then worry about non-normality or lack of fit?

Comment: I am not really sure how to get a curve after a multiple regression model. I am using STATA and regress to include all my variables, but after I use predict and plot it against the scatter plot, it is an angular line instead of a curve or a line.

Comment: That's right: a multiple regression model is not a curve. If multiple regression is the appropriate solution, then forget about curve fitting. Could you add a few words to your question to explain what it is you really need to do?

Comment: Sure,I will. I just tried a multiple regression model that seemed to fit, but the rvfplot was not ok, and the heteroskedasticity test also was p<0.001

Comment: That's progress! Could you post a plot of residuals *versus* fitted values? BTW, I was heartened to see that the response is a ratio (area per second), because I anticipated that analyzing its *reciprocal* would help make the residuals more homoscedastic. Consider regressing 1/MD-R (which is an interpretable quantity in units of s/mm^2) against the other variables. This transformation alone will not cure the problems in the univariate regression you show, but in combination with additional variables it might.

Comment: That is the plot that I checked. I can't post pictures in the comments, so here is a link : http://postimg.org/image/mz5lvev07/

Here is the same plot with the reciprocal MD_R: http://postimg.org/image/c2bg6sq4b/

By the way the site is telling me best not to continue here and do so on chat, but I don't have enough rep, so here I am :P